# Android HereMaps SDK Route Line Thickness?

Tags: android, here-api, heremaps

I am using the HereMaps SDK of Android with Premium edition.
Is there any way to set the thickness of the route line?
I can change the color with color & traveledColor properties of MapRoute class but I can not find any property about thickness.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please check MapPolyline class here "https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.11/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/mapping/MapPolyline.html",

it does set the width with setLineWidth method.

```
setLineWidth(int width)
Sets a line width, in pixels, for this MapPolyline, an int value within the [0..100] range.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I use MapRoute in order to draw the route. How can I set the line width with the MapRoute object?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use MapRoute You can use CustomizableScheme for that :

```
   CustomizableScheme scheme = map.createCustomizableScheme("newCustomScheme", Map.Scheme.NORMAL_DAY);
    
    scheme.setVariableValue(CustomizableVariables.RouteStyle.ROUTESTYLE_1_WIDTH , *Width in pixels* , range);
```

you can check the [CustomizableVariables.RouteStyle](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.18/api_reference_java/index.html) Class

if you want to use Polylines tho you can try this :

```
MapPolyline mp = new MapPolyline(new GeoPolyline(route.getRouteGeometry()));
 mp.setLineWidth(20);
 map.addMapObject(mp);
```