# Android SDK Route Navigation Customization

Tags: android, kotlin, here-api, heremaps-android-sdk

hello i'm trying to customize here navigation inside my app

is it possible to change the thickness of the route line inside the nav (
similar thread [Android HereMaps SDK Route Line Thickness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61586976/android-heremaps-sdk-route-line-thickness)
)?

is it possible to change the maximum/minimum zoom while I'm using  NavigationManager.MapUpdateMode.ROADVIEW?

and finally is it possible to move mapView.positionIndicator at the bottom of the screen inside navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Thickness of MapRoute object can't be adjusted.
2. There is no way to adjust max/min zoom level for ROADVIEW, you can try ROADVIEW_NOZOOM instead and control zooming by yourself.
3. Please use [Map.setTransformCenter](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.18/api_reference_java/content/com/here/android/mpa/mapping/Map.html#setTransformCenter-android.graphics.PointF-) to control the map movement center (number of pixel). For example, you have an 1080*1920 screen, you can use `map.setTransformCenter(new PointF((540.0), (1162.8)));` to shift the map movement center lower.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can change thickness of MapRoute

If you really want to use MapRoute You can use CustomizableScheme for that :

```
CustomizableScheme scheme = map.createCustomizableScheme("newCustomScheme", Map.Scheme.NORMAL_DAY);
    
scheme.setVariableValue(CustomizableVariables.RouteStyle.ROUTESTYLE_1_WIDTH , *Width in pixels* , range);
```

you can check the CustomizableVariables.RouteStyle Class

if you want to use Polylines tho you can try this :

```
MapPolyline mp = new MapPolyline(new GeoPolyline(route.getRouteGeometry()));
 mp.setLineWidth(20);
 map.addMapObject(mp);
```